# How do I get node.js to use CFML-style #hashed# variables?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, coldfusion

I'm building a Node.js framework and I love ColdFusion's `<cfoutput>` style hash-qualified variables.

I'm trying to work out how to achieve the same effect. For example:

```
<h1>
    #this.pageTitle#
</h1>
<div>
    #this.content()#
</div>
```

Comment: have you looked at usingg VM, http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html - just parse the source and match `#(.*)#` and replace with `' + $1 + '` and then run it in the context and catch the errors.

Comment: I like this idea, I didn't know about this module. I'm testing with it now to see if what I want o achieve is possible using this as I can add proper scope to the files this way. I've also updated the question with some html. Wasn't sure it was clear that I wanted to use html.

Comment: I have created a sample for you, tested and works fine, make sure you read all the docs and look at the source of the VM, so you know how it works and any risks that may arise.

Comment: Hey RobertPitt, thanks for this. I read the docs, seems like a lot of gotchas but I'm going to play with this solution as soon as I can find the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment I left in the main question above.

```
/**
 * Load the Virtual Machine
 */
var vm = require('vm');

/**
 * Template Data
 */
var template = "<h1>#this.content#</h1><div>#this.sitename()#</div>";

/**
 * Process method
 */
function compile(source)
{
    var __ = "this.__compiled = '";

    /**
     * Replace all template tags
     */
    __ += source.replace(/\#(.*?)\#/g, "' +$1+ '");

    return __ + "';";
}

/**
 * Create the context / scope, this can be anything from 'this', 'process' to 'require('fs')'
 */
var context = {
    content : "Robert Pitt",
    sitename : function(){
        return "http://robertpitt.me";
    }
};

/**
 * Compile the code within the sandbox
 */
var compiled = vm.runInNewContext(compile(template), context);

/**
 * Use compiled source:
 * value: <h1>Robert Pitt</h1><div>http://robertpitt.me</div>
 */
console.log(compiled);
```

Comment: Thanks guy! I'll have a look at this later, if you wanted to know what I am working on/where its going https://github.com/davemackintosh/ubuif

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks matey. Going to work with and on this to expand it further. You can see it here https://github.com/davemackintosh/ubuif/blob/master/library/Ubuif/Ubuivoo.js

Answer (score 0):

[CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) has [string interpolations](http://coffeescript.org/#strings):

```
author = "Wittgenstein"
quote  = "A picture is a fact. -- #{ author }"

sentence = "#{ 22 / 7 } is a decent approximation of π"
```

Comment: I'm not interested in CoffeeScript. Personally I find it pointless and in this case it can't be used since most of my framework is already built in standard JS. Thanks though